# Help incorporating a variable that I set to 0 even though the problem didn't explicitly ask for it.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

The equation that the problem is built around $$\cfrac{1}{1-\rho}(w-\pi)^{1-\rho} = \cfrac{1}{2} \left( \cfrac{1}{1-\rho}(w-x)^{1-\rho} \right) + \cfrac{1}{2} \left( \cfrac{1}{1-\rho}(w+y)^{1-\rho} \right)$$

In these problems, typically $w > 0$, $x > 0$, $y > 0$, $\pi \geq 0$ (it's not 3.14...)

The problem wants me to show that for $\rho > 1$, $y$ can never be sufficiently large for $$\cfrac{1}{1-\rho}(w-\pi)^{1-\rho} \leq \cfrac{1}{2} \left( \cfrac{1}{1-\rho}(w-x)^{1-\rho} \right) + \cfrac{1}{2} \left( \cfrac{1}{1-\rho}(w+y)^{1-\rho} \right)$$

when the following is satisfied.
$$\cfrac{x}{w} \geq 1 - 0.5^{1/(\rho-1)} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \rho \geq \cfrac{\log(0.5)+\log(1- x/w)}{\log(1-x/w)}$$

---

---

In a previous problem, I solved for $y$ in the first equation. Here's my work so far.

We know from part (b) that the minimum value of $y$ is given by
\begin{align*}
            y &= \left( 2(w-\pi)^{1-\rho} - (w-x)^{1-\rho} \right)^{1/(1-\rho)} - w
          \end{align*}
Which implies that the agent will accept a gamble that satisfies
\begin{align*}
 y &\geq \left( 2(w-\pi)^{1-\rho} - (w-x)^{1-\rho} \right)^{1/(1-\rho)} - w
\end{align*}
Define $-\gamma = 1-\rho$ where $\gamma \geq 0$
\begin{align*}
y &\geq \left( 2(w-\pi)^{-\gamma} - (w-x)^{-\gamma} \right)^{-(1/\gamma)} - w \\ 
y &\geq \left(\frac{1}{ \left( \cfrac{2}{(w-\pi)^\gamma} - \cfrac{1}{(w-x)^\gamma}  \right)}\right)^{1/\gamma} \\
\end{align*}
For fixed $\gamma$ we see that $y$ approaches $\infty$ as
\begin{align*}
\cfrac{2}{(w-\pi)^\gamma} &= \cfrac{1}{(w-x)^\gamma} \\
 2(w-x)^\gamma &= (w-\pi)^\gamma \\
 2^{1/\gamma}(w-x) &= w - \pi \\
 (w-x) &= \cfrac{w-\pi}{2^{1/\gamma}} \\
 x &= w - \cfrac{w-\pi}{2^{1/\gamma}} \\
x &= \cfrac{2^{1/\gamma}w - w - \pi}{2^{1/\gamma}} \\
            x &= \cfrac{w(2^{1/\gamma} - 1) - \pi}{2^{1/\gamma}}
          \end{align*}

Now let $\pi = 0$ (no risk premium)
\begin{align*}
 x &= \cfrac{w(2^{1/\gamma} - 1)}{2^{1/\gamma}} \\
 \cfrac{x}{w} &= 1 - \left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)^{1/\gamma} = 1 - \left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)^{1/(1-\rho)}
\end{align*}

---

I don't feel comfortable about setting $\pi=0$. While it feels intuitive to set it equal to zero (have the gamble be a "free insurance policy"), if $\pi$ were equal to $0$, the problem should have specified it. Is there a way I can show that $\pi$ disappears in the solution without setting it equal to 0?